# How can I use LLVM IR within Cling (or another REPL-like interactively)?

Tags: clang, llvm, read-eval-print-loop, llvm-ir, cling

I'm learning LLVM IR, and would like to use it interactively.

Cling supports interactive Clang, and works very well.  Cling supports the `asm` directive, allowing you to use native ASM interactively.  Cling also advertises to support "any language Clang does".  Yet, I cannot figure any way to make Cling work with LLVM IR.  (Although Clang can assemble LLVM IR, it doesn't seem to have an inline LLVM IR directive, only an inline `asm` directive.)

`lli` is one shot only, not interactive.

Is there a way to use LLVM IR with Cling?
If not, is there another way to use LLVM IR interactively?

Comment: From what I know, there is nothing that can help you at the moment.